# "RAZR i" name in ACRA report

Tags: android, crash, acra, device-name

I've integrated the ACRA crash report tool in my application. A great number of user that has "RAZR i" apologize about a start up issue but I'm not able to recognize this kind of device in ACRA report. Some of you know which kind of name has this device?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ACRA issue. A quick Google shows that this is likely the Motorala Razr. Use a search engine

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've previous searched on google but I was not able to retrieve this information. Could you please let me have the link. Also now I'm not finding it.

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=RAZR&oq=RAZR&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l3j69i60j69i61.1955j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Motorola "RAZR i" phone is unique in the CPU it uses - instead of ARM cpu, it uses Intel Atom processor. Therefore, if you employ any native library in your app, you should build it also for "x86" processor. Otherwise the application will not be able to start, as it won't use ARM native libraries. However, Google Play would also not let your app deploy to devices with Intel x86 processor, so maybe you do have an x86 library, but there is a bug in it? Best thing would be to test your app on an emulator with x86 processor - Google Android SDK provides such emulators, but I prefer Genymotion emulators in my work - http://www.genymotion.com/

Otherwise there is not enough information in your post to help more. Maybe paste the entire ACRA stack trace, that could tell us more.

Greg